# Aggregate Functions To Pull More Record Field Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, group-by, aggregate-functions

I would like to know what would be the best way to get the data from a specific row when I use a Group By query. The real query is more complex than the example I'm providing here so I'm looking for something other than a sub-select on the Sales table.

I'm using MSSQL 2008 and I would like something that allow me to get the date field from the Sales record that has the max(amount).

**Query**

```
select uid, firstName, lastName, AmountFromTagetedRow, DateFromTargetedRow,
from users u inner join 
     sales s on u.uid = s.custID
group by uid, firstName, lastName
order by uid
```

**USERS**

```
uid  firstName  lastName
1    Sam        Smith
2    Joe        Brown
3    Kim        Young
```

**SALES**

```
sid  Custid  date        amount ...
1    1       2016-01-02  100
2    3       2016-01-12  485
3    1       2016-01-22  152
4    2       2016-02-01  156
5    1       2016-02-02  12
6    1       2016-03-05  84
7    2       2016-03-10  68
```

**RESULTS**

```
uid  firstName  LastName  amount  date
1    Sam        Smith     152     2016-01-22
2    Joe        Brown     156     2016-02-01
3    Kim        Young     485     2016-01-12
```

Comment: Presuming **Results** is your desired output?

Comment: What do you mean by _TargetedRow_? What aggregation function are you looking to perform?

Comment: Chris, sorry if the questions wasn't very clear. Sean answered the question. I had my head stuck on doing it in one Group By statement, but using WITH and ROW_NUMBER() is the best way to get what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your posted query doesn't match your amount but something like this should get you pointed in the right direction.

```
with SortedResults as
(
    select uid
        , firstName
        , lastName
        , AmountFromTagetedRow
        , DateFromTargetedRow
        , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by u.uid order by AmountFromTagetedRow desc) as RowNum
    from users u inner join 
         sales s on u.uid = s.custID
    group by uid
        , firstName
        , lastName
)

select *
from SortedResults
where RowNum = 1
order by uid
```

Comment: Thanks Sean. I was getting tunnel vision on this one and forgot that I could use WITH for this.